# Creating New Dynamic Column in a Power BI Table: Count values in another column and return different response based on the filter context

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I am quite new to DAX and filter context so any help is appreciated.

I am looking to add another column to a table visual in Power BI based on a new measure. I need the measure to do the following:

- Count the occurrences of a name in the column 'Name'.
- If there is one count of a name in the table return 'Out' in the new column.
- If there are two counts of a name in the table return 'In' in the new column.
- I would like this to be dynamic, so that the value can change between 'In' and 'Out' depending on the filter context.

Example below showing how it should work:

Table1 (no filters) John shows as 'In' in the new column as his name appears twice.

| Name | Department | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | HR | In |
| John | Marketing | In |
| Julie | Marketing | Out |
| Jake | Sales | Out |

If you then filter Department to show just Marketing (using a slicer on the same page), I would like John to change to 'Out' as there is now only one occurrence of the name John.

| Name | Department | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Marketing | Out |
| Julie | Marketing | Out |

I cannot get this dynamic nature to work!

I have created this measure, which does **not** change dynamically with the filters, all rows are listed with 'Out' no matter what filters are applied and how many counts of a name there are:

```
New Column =

VAR Name_Count = COUNTROWS(VALUES(Table1[Name]))

RETURN
IF(
Name_Count > 1,
"In",
"Out"
)
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the solution - it worked perfectly! 

To improve this I would also like to add a condition where the new measure only applies on rows where the value in the Department column is either 'Marketing' or 'Sales' - so rows with other departments would be null/blank. Is it possible to add this condition into the DAX formula? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
New Column = 
  var thisName = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Name])
  var nameCount = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table1), [Name] = thisName))
  var result = IF(nameCount > 1, "In", "Out")
  return IF(ISINSCOPE('Table1'[Name]), result)
```

The key is `ALLSELECTED` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax